# Why is the MySQL table name appended to my variable names on an ODBC data pull?

Tags: mysql, odbc, sas

I am pulling data from a `MySQL` Server using an `ODBC` connection to the `MySQL` tables. Unfortunately, the table names are now being appended to the variables, which means I have to run an extra step after the data pull to rename every variable for use. Why is this happening and how can I prevent this?

E.G.,
MySQL table Sched has the following variables `MAPID, TEST, TYPE, APPOINT`, etc. but when I pull the data they come down as: `Sched_MAPID, Sched_TEST, Sched_TYPE, Sched_APPOINT`, etc.

I am using SAS 9.3 64b and setting a lib ref that includes the libname (MySQLLib, type of connection (odbc), the `DSN`, username and password. The connection obviously tests fine or I wouldn't be able to see the data, much less pull it. Basically, I set the data using the following:

```
libname MySQLLib odbc dsn=MySQLSSH user=&MySQLID pwd=&sqlpwd;

Data MySQLSched; 
Set MySQLLib.Sched; 
run;
```

Generally, a local SAS table (MySQLSched) is created that I can then manipulate and use as I need, without further touching the original Sched table. I still can, but every variable has the table name appended.

I am not sure if this is a SAS issue or a `MySQL` issue. I will also ask this same question in the SAS forums. IF I receive a pertinent answer there, I will update this post with that answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a schema set up?  I would guess this is a MySQL or your ODBC driver issue, as it's not something I've seen in connecting to other DBMSs.

Comment: That's a good question. I don't admin the MySQL server, so I am not sure. However, we recently dumped the database for renaming purposes and that is when the appending began. Is this something I can do, or do I need my Admin guy to set the 'schema'?